# kubernetes resource level RBAC with object filtering

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

i'm doing some resource level RBAC for k8s  custom objects and finding it difficult to get filter resources using native k8s calls

`cluster` is my custom CRD   and user `john` has access to only one crd instance not all instances of CRD using k8s native RBAC

```
➜  k get clusters
NAME               AGE
aws-gluohfhcwo     3d2h
azure-cikivygyxd   3d1h

➜  k get clusters --as=john
Error from server (Forbidden): clusters.operator.biqmind.com is forbidden: User "ranbir" cannot list resource "clusters" in API group "operator.biqmind.com" in the namespace "biqmind"

➜  k get clusters --as=john aws-gluohfhcwo
NAME             AGE
aws-gluohfhcwo   3d2h
```

i have explicitly specify object name to get the list of objects to which user is authenticated.   any suggestions on how this can be solved?

full rbac is posted here

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: biqmind
  name: cluster-admin-aws-gluohfhcwo
rules:
- apiGroups: ["operator.biqmind.com"]
  resources: ["clusters"]
  resourceNames: ["aws-gluohfhcwo"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin-aws-gluohfhcwo-binding
  namespace: biqmind
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: cluster-admin-aws-gluohfhcwo
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: ranbir
```

Answer (score 0):

> User "ranbir" cannot list resource "clusters" in API group "operator.biqmind.com" in the namespace "biqmind"

You must add RBAC permissions with the verb `list` for the specified user in the specified namespace, to let that user `list` "clusters".

When doing

```
kubectl get clusters --as=john aws-gluohfhcwo
```

you use the RBAC verb `get`, but to list without specifying a specific name, the user also need permission to `list`.

Example of giving `list` permission, **without resourceName:**:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: biqmind
  name: cluster-admin-aws-gluohfhcwo
rules:
- apiGroups: ["operator.biqmind.com"]
  resources: ["clusters"]
  resourceNames: ["aws-gluohfhcwo"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]

- apiGroups: ["operator.biqmind.com"]
  resources: ["clusters"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

Comment: i have updated the question with rbac that i used,   it already has list permission.

Comment: @debianmaster I updated my answer with a permission without `resourceName` since that is not aplicable for a `list` operation.

Comment: the second  -apiGroups will expose all the resources in the namespaces making the first statement void of providing access only on resource `aws-gluohfhcwo`

Comment: If you want to `list` you need to expose all "cluster" resources in the namespace, yes.

Comment: looks like there is no way to do this https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54079  do you think Open policy agent can do this?

Comment: But if you only want to `list` a specific resource - it does **not make sense**. But you can `get` a specific resource. What do you really want to do? What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: yes, you can not watch without list, with the current kubernetes functionality, as what I know.

Comment: `clusters` have owners,  owners will share access to other users for admin/readonly operations.    in my implementation all cluster objects are in one single namespace.   so i want to provide rbac on individual objects

Answer (score 0):

Enforcing [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) on the user side is easy in concept. You can create RoleBindings for individual users, but this is not the recommended path as there’s a high risk of operator insanity.

The better approach for sane RBAC is to create that your users map to; how this mapping is done is dependent on your cluster’s authenticator (e.g. the aws-iam-authenticator for EKS uses mapRoles to map a role ARN to a set of groups).

Groups and the APIs they have access to are ultimately determined based on an organization’s needs, but a generic reader (for new engineers just getting the hang of things), writer (for your engineers), and admin (for you) role is a good start. (Hey, it’s better than admin for everyone.)

Here is example of configuration file:

```
# An example reader ClusterRole – ClusterRole so you’re not worried about namespaces at this time. Remember, we’re talking generic reader/writer/admin roles.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
name: reader
rules:
– apiGroups: [“*”]
resources:
– deployments
– configmaps
– pods
– secrets
– services
verbs:
– get
– list
– watch
---
# An example reader ClusterRoleBinding that gives read permissions to
# the engineering and operations groups
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
name: reader-binding
roleRef:
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
kind: ClusterRole
name: reader
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: umbrella:engineering
- kind: Group
  name: umbrella:operations
---
# An example writer ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
name: writer
rules:
- apiGroups: [“*”]
resources:
- deployments
- configmaps
- pods
- secrets
- services
verbs:
- create
- delete
- patch
- update
---
# An example writer ClusterRoleBinding that gives write permissions to
# the operations group
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
name: reader-binding
roleRef:
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
kind: ClusterRole
name: reader
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: umbrella:operations
```

Here is exact explanation: [rbac-article](https://thenewstack.io/three-realistic-approaches-to-kubernetes-rbac/).

**Take notice that default Roles and Role Bindings**

API servers create a set of default ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding objects. Many of these are system: prefixed, which indicates that the resource is “owned” by the infrastructure. Modifications to these resources can result in non-functional clusters. One example is the system:node ClusterRole. This role defines permissions for kubelets. If the role is modified, it can prevent kubelets from working.

All of the default cluster roles and rolebindings are labeled with `kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults`.

**Remember about auto-reconciliation**

At each start-up, the API server updates default cluster roles with any missing permissions, and updates default cluster role bindings with any missing subjects. This allows the cluster to repair accidental modifications, and to keep roles and rolebindings up-to-date as permissions and subjects change in new releases.

To opt out of this reconciliation, set the rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate annotation on a default cluster role or rolebinding to false. Be aware that missing default permissions and subjects can result in non-functional clusters.

Auto-reconciliation is enabled in Kubernetes version **1.6+** when the RBAC authorizer is active.

Useful article: [understanding-rbac](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/08/07/understanding-kubernestes-rbac/).